# Regular Expression allowing only 0-24 float point numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating WPF TextBox extension control which must allow the following inputs only by using regular expression:

- Number must be within 0 and 24 (0 <= number <= 24)
- must allow only max two digits after floating point, e.g: 0.5, 0.55, 23.2, 23.55

It's pretty hard for me to find out which regular expression will allow to pass that range. I've started with:

```
^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$
```

But it does not quite match my requirements. So I'm asking for a help to get this regular expression.

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried?

Comment: Ok, I tried this ^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to get an headache using regex? Simply parse the text, check the range of the values and the number of decimals :

```
bool IsValid(string text) {
    decimal candidate;
    if(decimal.TryParse(text, out candidate)){

        if(
            candidate >= 0 && // Check lower bound
            candidate <= 24 && // CHeck higher bound
            Math.Round(candidate, 2) == candidate // Check number of decimals
        ) {
            return true;
        }

    }
     return false;
}
```

Moreover, you will avoid globalization issues (using `.`, `,` depending on the culture) by letting the system handle this.

Comment: Possibly because all existing validation is done by regex, and it is not desirable to introduce a new validation pattern? (but I do agreee with your point)

Comment: I believe Regular expressions are great tools, used wisely. I don't believe regexing the world is a good idea, because it's hard to read, hard to maintain and can even lead sometimes to security issue (google for evil regex). But it's true that validing using regex can stay consistent with other validation in the app, it depends on the context.

Comment: @paul - Even if all the other fasteners are nails, you shouldn't use a hammer on the one screw in the project.

Comment: I'm in agreement. If it wasn't for the OP specifically stating 'only by using regular expression' then I wouldn't even consider using one to try to validate a range.

Answer (score 4):

try this pattern:

```
^24(?:\\.00?)?|(?:2[0-3]|1?[0-9])(?:\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Comment: You only need to double the backspace if you don't use a `@"..."` literal string. Other than that, looks good.

Comment: There's one thing actually. It validates numbers like `24.01` up to `24.99`.